# Determine All positive solutions: $54x+21y=906$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine All positive solutions: 
$54x+21y=906$

so first I tried to see if the gcd$(54,21)|906$ which is true since the gcd of $(54,21)=3$

Then I tried to find one solution by writing a linear equation of $a$ and $b$
So far I had

$3=12-9(1)$

$3=12-[21-12(1)](1)$

$3=2(12)-1(20)$

$3=2(54-21(2))-1(20)$

$3=2(54)+...$

Now this last line is a problem. Why do I have an extra $20$? Did  I do something wrong?

Comment: I understand the problem, but I'm not sure I understand your attempts at a solution for it. Did you mean that gcd(54,21)|906? Since you only want positive solutions, you can solve this without number theory by solving your equation for y, graphing it, and looking for integer pairs on the line in the first quadrant.

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake, gcd(54,21)|906
Also my teacher is requiring us to solve this using number theory since I'm in a number theory course

Answer (score 2):

You may simplify the equation without any harm
$$54x+21y=906$$
$$18x+7y=302$$
where $gcd\left(18,7\right)=1$.

Try to represent the diophantine equation from the initial $gcd$ form:
$$18=2\cdot7+4$$
$$7=4+3$$
$$4=3+1$$
$$1=4-3$$
As intended $gcd\left(18,7\right)=gcd\left(7,4\right)=gcd\left(4,3\right)=1$. Take the opposite path:
$$1=4-\left(7-4\right)$$
$$1=-7+2\cdot4$$
$$1=-7+2\cdot\left(18-2\cdot7\right)$$
$$1=-7+2\cdot18-4\cdot7$$
$$18\cdot\left(2\right)+7\cdot\left(-5\right)=1$$
Then $\left(2,-5\right)$ is the solution of the diophantine equation $18x+7y=1$, but if you multiply the entire equation by $302$ you find a possible answer,
$$18\cdot\left(604\right)+7\cdot\left(-1510\right)=302$$
Thus, the general solution to this equation is given by
$$x=604+7\cdot k$$
$$y=-1510-18\cdot k$$
Now, if you are interested only in positive values of $\left(x,y\right)$, you need to find out which values of $k$ this is possible.

First, check $x$ intervals:
$$604+7k>0$$
$$7k>-604$$
$$k>-\frac{604}{7}$$
$$k>-86.28571$$
$$k>-87$$
Second, check $y$ intervals:
$$-1510-18k>0$$
$$-1510>18k$$
$$k<-\frac{1510}{18}$$
$$k<-83.88888$$
$$k<-83$$
Then, the resulting interval is $-87<k<-83$, so $k$ has three possible values
$$k\in\left\{-86,-85,-84\right\}$$
For $k=-86$ the value of $\left(x,y\right)$ is
$$x=604+7\cdot\left(-86\right)=2$$
$$y=-1510-18\cdot\left(-86\right)=38$$
For $k=-85$ the value of $\left(x,y\right)$ is
$$x=604+7\cdot\left(-85\right)=9$$
$$y=-1510-18\cdot\left(-85\right)=20$$
For $k=-84$ the value of $\left(x,y\right)$ is
$$x=604+7\cdot\left(-84\right)=16$$
$$y=-1510-18\cdot\left(-84\right)=2$$
Thus, $\left(2,38\right)$, $\left(9,20\right)$, $\left(16,2\right)$ are the solutions you are looking for.

Comment: Your answers seems slightly different from what is given by Ross. It would be great if you can resolve the difference in your answer (i.e. if the other answer is wrong, say a few words about what he did wrong there.)

Comment: About Ross' answers: (16,2), (9,18), (2,34) are slightly different than mine because there are some miscalculations. The answer (16,2) is correct. But (2,34) is wrong, if you make x=2, then y=(302 - 18*2)/7=38 not 34. The same applies to (9,18) also wrong, if you make x=9, then y=(302 - 18*9)/7=20 not 18.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the question is about positive integral solutions.

This problem is known - in general - as the problem of determining the so-called "Numerical semigroup" generated by two positive integers $a, b$. See, this math overflow post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121826/on-the-set-of-numbers-generated-by-integer-linear-combination-of-two-real-number, and the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup.

When $a$ and $b$ are coprime, one can express every positive integer $s$ that is larger or equal to $(a-1)(b-1)$ as solution $s= xa+yb$ with $x, y\in \mathbb{N}$. From this you can easily get a statement for the case when they are not coprime.

Note: I think that this problem is also known as "coin problem".

Here you can find an explicit guide for finding the positive solutions:
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/divisibility_5_print.pdf

Comment: Just for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find a solution. As you note, the coefficients have a GCD of 3, so let's divide that out, getting $18x+7y=302$.  For small numbers, you can just do it by hand.  We $x \le 16$ because $17 \cdot 18=306$ is too large.  We note that $16 \cdot 18 + 2 \cdot 7=302$  Now for smaller solutions, we can trade $7$ in $x$ for $16$ in $y$.  Since we can only do the trade twice, there are three solutions $(16,2),(9,18),(2,34)$